# Python Selenium - Interact with the next WebElement object in a list

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of web elements like this:

```
menu = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="partEl__1o8vO"]')
```

For all the web elements contained in list `menu`
I have to perform a click, but with my code below the first element in the list is clicked n times instead of clicking one time on all the elements in the list:

```
menu = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="partEl__1o8vO"]')
for index, value in enumerate(menu):
    value = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="TableRow_clickableRow__1uMJO"]')
    value.click()
```

I know that I'm not looping correctly, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing debugging details, but I guess the following should work:

```py
menu = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="partEl__1o8vO"]')
for value in menu:
    value.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="TableRow_clickableRow__1uMJO"]').click()
```

In case clicking the menu options performs refreshing the page the following should help:

```py
menu = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="partEl__1o8vO"]')
for value in menu:
    value.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="TableRow_clickableRow__1uMJO"]').click()
    menu = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="partEl__1o8vO"]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's working now, and I understand now where I didn't managed to click on all the elements thanks a lot !